# My code is not working ($h.= ')

Tags: php

Can anyone help me for this why doesn't my code work?

```
 $h.= '             <a href="#">'mysql_result($res,$z,"name")'</a>';
```

It gives me an error because of the <a href

Comment: Remove space and add `.`:-`$h.= '<a href="#">'.mysql_result($res,$z,"name").'</a>';`

Comment: Deniz please mark and up-vote the answer for others help.

Comment: Deniz please mark and up-vote the answer for others help.

Comment: Deniz after asking also you didn't mark the answer. I am deleting my answer because of this in-appropriate behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $h .= '<a href="#">'.mysql_result($res,$z,"name").'</a>';
```

Should work now
`.` before `mysql_result` and after.

Also take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) it will help you to understand String Operators and etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate.

```
$h.= '             <a href="#">' . mysql_result($res,$z,"name") . '</a>';
```

Anyway, I would suggest you to put `mysql_result($res,$z,"name")` into a variable, to increase readability and avoid executing the function every time you call it.

I mean:

```
$name = mysql_result($res,$z,"name");
$h.= '             <a href="#">' . $name . '</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you you guys saved me today.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and select one answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $h.= '<a href="#">'.mysql_result($res,$z,"name").'</a>';
```

You are missing `.` the [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)